# Unable to locate element - Can I wait for it to load?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium to scrape prices from a few websites. I learned about `xpath` and though it was a great way to select elements.

I'm having a hard time selecting the price from this page. I feel like maybe the element hasn't loaded yet which was one of the reasons I started using Selenium.

Is `xpath` really as reliable as I thought?

```
from selenium import webdriver

DRIVER_PATH = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH, options=options)

url = "https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/pdp/zipcode-design-evan-726-wide-square-arm-convertible-sofa-zpcd1679.html"
xpath = '//*[@id="bd"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/span'
driver.get(url)
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text

print(price)

driver.quit()
```

My code gives this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="bd"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/span"}
```

Comment: Firstly make sure the xpath is correctly locating the element. try using time.sleep(5) just for testing. Then if it is working, use Expected Conditions to wait for element visibility

Comment: Should I try full xpath instead?

Comment: is the xpath you have used is working? Try including html structure of the page in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wait and print the value out.

```
elem=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='bd']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/span")))
print(elem.text)
```

Outputs

```
$779.99
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```